# Comment Box is not hiding after posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Comment box is not hiding after posting any thing.
currently using AJAX to post data. Just want to hide input area just after submitting it.
here is fully
**[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DkAMN/)**

I also this code to open the comment box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".comment_button").click(function() {

        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");

        $("#slidepanel" + I).slideToggle(300);
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

        return false;
    });
});
```

suggesting you check the example **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DkAMN/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the `success` callback:

```
$("#slidepanel" + Id).hide();
```

Or, to match the fade in:

```
$("#slidepanel" + Id).slideToggle(300);
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DkAMN/1/) for updated jsFiddle. Note the success callback will not be called in jsFiddle, since the php page does not exist at `http://fiddle.jshell.net/DkAMN/1/show/insertajax.php`.

Comment: Okz i will try this. 
But is there any way make it hide just after posting comment. weather it get success or not.

Comment: Yeah - just add the `$("#slidepanel" + Id).hide();` call to after the post - have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/DkAMN/3/

Comment: thanks for the help both code working like champ. thanks again. will accept it wait 10 min